# Is it possible to update a text file which is inside a blob container in Azure from Boomi?

Tags: azure, blob, boomi

I only found ways to create or overwrite files in blob containers from a Boomi process.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes. I'm using Connector Shape in Boomi. The Create process is working well, it creates the new file in the blob container.  

I have a No Data start, a Message, a Set Properites Shape (which contains azureBlobName) and the Connector Shape.

I know there is only Create, Delete and List operations here, but is there any way to update an existing file...

I found some info like BLOB_TYPE - APPEND_BLOB, but nothing works.

Comment: You can't directly edit a file stored as a Blob, you need to replace it.